# SQL Server Table Design (Products and revisions)

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I am creating a new database.  The main table is products.  Each of those products have revisions.  Each revisions have information about them.

So say for products I have (Prod1, Prod2, Prod3, etc).  Then say Prod1 has revisions (1, 2), Prod2 has revisions (1), Prod3 has revisions (1, 2, 3), and so on.

Then each revision has information about them.  Prod1.Rev1 has info (info1, info2, info3, etc)  Prod2.Rev1 has info (info1, info2, info3, etc) and so on.

The information might be in different groups as well.  So info1, info2 might be one group, info3 and info4 might be a different group.

What is the best way to set up the data base for this scenario?

Comment: Sounds like you will need a table named Groups, for identifying what group an info item belongs to??

Answer (score 1):

This is my thought as to how to structure this in a relational way, Products would have a one-to-many relationship with revisions, so Revisions would have a foreign key which matches the Primary key value of Products. Revisions has a one-to-many relationship with Info items, so Info would hold a foreign key value which relates to the Primary key value of Revisions. Groups would then also have a one-to-many relationship with info items, so Items would then also need to hold a foreign key which relates to the primary key of Groups. I hope this helps.

Comment: Forget about the groups of info.  That is another beast.  That is what I was thinking though.  Have a table to hold the product with a product id, then have a revisions table with a revision id and the product id(foreign key).  So the info would have a foreign key to the revision table, but not the product table, correct?

Comment: That is correct. The relationship of info is directly with revisions, as products have a relationship with revisions and revisions have a relationship with info, you could join the 3 tables together if you need data from all of them.